# How to get iid, openudid parameter values from my android device?

Tags: android

The github script requires device_id, iid, openudid

device_id was able to find out using the application for android, the rest is not clear how to extract, did not understand what it is.

Perhaps you know how to get the values of iid and openudid?

Thank!

[github](https://github.com/snuzi/tiktok-scraper-php)

> Use this scraper In order to use and make requests to Tiktok API, some extra device parameters are needed. These parameters should be extracted from your mobile phone by using a man in the middle proxy. I used PacketCapture for Android, you may use any proxy application you like. Grab the following parameters: device_id,iid,openudid.